# Flex 4: Enumerating Spark List items

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How to enumerate items of Spark List component after setting *dataProvider* property?

I mean accessing them as *DisplayObject* instances.

Comment: Are you talking about from within the List? Or from outside the list? Are you saying the dataProvider consists of an arrayCollection of displayObjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `list.dataGroup.numElements`, calling `list.dataGroup.getElementAt(i)`:

```
var i:int = 0;
var n:int = list.dataGroup.numElements;
for (i; i < n; i++)
{
    // getElementAt returns an IVisualElement, but most displayobjects
    // in a list will be IVisualElement (which a UIComponent implements)
    var displayObject:DisplayObject = list.dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as DisplayObject;
}
```