# getChildren() in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

i have this function in my project

```
public function changeFormItemsLabelWidth(form:Form, width:int):void
{
    var formItemsArray:Array = form.getChildren();
    for( var i:int = 0; i < formItemsArray.length; i++){
        if(formItemsArray[i].className == "FormItem"){
            var formItem:FormItem = formItemsArray[i] as FormItem;
            formItem.setStyle("labelWidth", width);
        }
    }
```

and i'm getting this error:

**1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildren through a reference with static type spark.components:Form.**

Can someone tell me how can i replace getchildren method? because i'm migration to flex 4 and this method no longer exists.

**EDIT:**

Tanks for the help i did something like this and it works

```
public function changeFormItemsLabelWidth(form:Form, width:int):void
{

    var it:int = 0;
    var n:int = form.numElements;
    for (it; it < n; it++)
    {
        var formItemsArray:Array = form.getElementAt(it) as Array;
    }

    for( var i:int = 0; i < formItemsArray.length; i++){
        if(formItemsArray[i].className == "FormItem"){
            var formItem:FormItem = formItemsArray[i] as FormItem;
            formItem.setStyle("labelWidth", width);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `form.numElements` and iterate. Each element is reachable via `form.getElementAt( iterator )`.

Comment: im new at this can u explain this iterate thing?

Comment: Its just a fancy word for a loop. See the example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554075/flex-4-enumerating-spark-list-items

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't ask this, and I'm not sure about the problem you are solving, but your code where you manipulate the size of the FormItems outside of the standard lifecycle functions kind of smells funny.  Just a suggestion.